# Netbeans does not update my Netbeans-Platform application when I modify modules files

Tags: java, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-7.3

I'm currently having troube developing a Netbeans Application on a 7.3RC2 base : I have a few modules of my own, and when I run the application (from the module in netbeans), nothing appears to change since yesterday. Looks like my "executable" files are frozen, no matter what I'm doing.

I tried cleaning the modules, recreating them and import the source code, desperatly recreate the full project and paste the sources into it... no way.

Then, I wondered if there was a kind of "execution folder" which would contain some data kidding me.

I did some search on Google and SO, but found nothing answering this problem.

Any idea is welcome !

[EDIT 1]

It seems my Netbeans app is using an old module JAR, and does not update it despite of module clean&build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !

Something unexpectedly went wrong with the "Public APIs" configuration in *all* my modules and they where in "autoload" state, I don't know why.

I had the idea to manually uncheck and re-check all necessary checkboxes, and all is going right now.